# Performance Issue when setting connection information Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have developed a method that sets the Crystal Reports Connection.

This method first grabs the connection string from the config file creates a Crystal Reports ConnectionInfo object.

The following code then takes over 5 seconds to run:

```
Dim myTables As Tables = report.Database.Tables
Dim myTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = New TableLogOnInfo()

myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
```

Then this code takes over 6 seconds to run:

```
For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo)
    myTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName
    myTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName
    myTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID
    myTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password
Next
```

This only occurs the first time that the form is loaded, the subsequent times it is

335ms (as compared to 5349ms)
and
52ms (as compared to 6228ms)

However, when the application is reloaded the same slow times re-occur.

There are not many different tables in my report generally 3 or less. Only 1 table in this case.

This is currently in test and VS2008 and SQLServer2005 are both running locally. The same issue does occur in the QA environment as well, where the application is run on the client and the database is on a server on the same LAN.

So my question is, can I improve the speed of this portion of code? Why does it take so long to set the report connection information? Am I doing connections to the report incorrectly?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It takes a while to load the massive crystal libraries. Are you sure it's not the `report.Load()` that is taking a long time.

Comment: I've got a StopWatch starting and stopping around these chunks of code, so I don't think it's the Load() method. I don't actually call the Load method anywhere, I do however do myReport.ExportToDisk() and then I also show the report in a new report form display window.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in debug mode to see if you can narrow it down to a specific line of code?

Comment: So you're using strongly typed reports? Also, why do you create a new logininfo, apply it, and then set all the properties again?

Comment: Also, I wonder if the `SetDatabaseLogon` method is any faster.

Comment: I have also posted a question at the SAP/Crystal Reports forums and received a response there from the author of this article suggesting that it may be of assistance. (http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/library/uuid/8029cc96-6ff3-2b10-47a2-b30ea790ea5b&overridelayout=true)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is:

```
Dim report = New ReportDocument

Try
        report.Load(filename, OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)

        'do this for each unique database connection
        report.SetDatabaseLogon("user","password","server","database")

        'continue processing...    

Catch
        'preserve stack trace
        Throw

End Try
```